# Solving "mv: Argument list too long"?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, mv

I have a folder with more than a million files that needs sorting, but I can't really do anything because `mv` outputs this message all the time

```
-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long
```

I'm using this command to move extension-less files:

```
mv -- !(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) targetdir/
```

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Comment: A quick hack that did but doesn't count as a general solution is: if you know a way to partition all these files  (e.g. A???.txt and B???.doc) in more manageable numbers, you could just move all the A files first and the B files next.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) is the tool for the job. That, or [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) with `-exec … {} +`. These tools run a command several times, with as many arguments as can be passed in one go.

Both methods are easier to carry out when the variable argument list is at the end, which isn't the case here: the final argument to `mv` is the destination. With GNU utilities (i.e. on non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), the `-t` option to `mv` is useful, to pass the destination first.

If the file names have no whitespace nor any of `\"'` and don't start with `-`¹, then you can simply provide the file names as input to `xargs` (the `echo` command is a bash builtin, so it isn't subject to the command line length limit; if you see `!: event not found`, you need to enable globbing syntax with `shopt -s extglob`):

```
echo !(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) | xargs mv -t targetdir --
```

You can use the `-0` option to `xargs` to use null-delimited input instead of the default quoted format.

```
printf '%s\0' !(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) | xargs -0 mv -t targetdir --
```

Alternatively, you can generate the list of file names with `find`. To avoid recursing into subdirectories, use `-type d -prune`. Since no action is specified for the listed image files, only the other files are moved.

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o \
       -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.bmp' -o \
       -exec mv -t targetdir/ {} +
```

(This includes dot files, unlike the shell wildcard methods.)

If you don't have GNU utilities, you can use an intermediate shell to get the arguments in the right order. This method works on all POSIX systems.

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o \
       -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' -o -name '*.bmp' -o \
       -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' targetdir/ {} +
```

---

In zsh, you can load the [`mv` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-mv):

```
setopt extended_glob
zmodload zsh/files
mv -- ^*.(jpg|png|bmp) targetdir/
```

or if you prefer to let `mv` and other names keep referring to the external commands:

```
setopt extended_glob
zmodload -Fm zsh/files b:zf_\*
zf_mv -- ^*.(jpg|png|bmp) targetdir/
```

or with ksh-style globs:

```
setopt ksh_glob
zmodload -Fm zsh/files b:zf_\*
zf_mv -- !(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) targetdir/
```

Alternatively, using GNU `mv` and [`zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs):

```
autoload -U zargs
setopt extended_glob
zargs -- ./^*.(jpg|png|bmp) -- mv -t targetdir/ --
```

---

<sup>¹ with some `xargs` implementations, file names must also be valid text in the current locale. Some would also consider a file named `_` as indicating the end of input (can be avoided with `-E ''`)</sup>

Comment: The first two commands returned "-bash: !: event not found" and the next two did not move any files at all. I'm on CentOS 6.5 if you should know

Comment: @Dominique I used the same globbing syntax that you used in your question. You'll need `shopt -s extglob` to enable it. I'd missed a step in the `find` commands, I've fixed them.

Comment: I'm getting this with the find command "find: invalid expression; you have used a binary operator '-o' with nothing before it." I will now try the other ones.

Comment: @Dominique The `find` commands I've posted (now) work. You must have left off a part when copy-pasting.

Comment: Gilles, for the find commands, why not use the "not" operator, `!`? It's more explicit and easier to understand than the odd trailing `-o`. For example, `! -name '*.jpg' -a ! -name '*.png' -a ! -name '*.bmp'`

Comment: @CivFan Now work out what it needs to be with the pruning of directories other than `.`. I don't think it's clearer than using `-o`. `-o` is a very common programming idiom: a list of patterns, where the first match is taken.

Comment: I still get `xargs: mv: Argument list too long`

Comment: @sam Ask a new question that contains the exact command you ran.

Comment: I have 80000 Chinese title files, `echo !(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) | xargs mv -t targetdir` successful move 40000+ files.But left 30000+ files with error  `mv: invalid option -- '▒'`

Comment: @Mithril You have file names with special characters, possibly spaces. As I state in my answer, this solution does not work with such file names. You have to use one of the other 7 solutions I propose.

Comment: @Gilles If I understand correctly, **all** `bash` builtins, unlike external tools, are ok with extremely large numbers of arguments? Is there some point to the documentation of this please?

Comment: `mv: illegal option -- t`

Comment: @geoidesic As I wrote in my answer, you need the GNU version for that. Not macOS, busybox, BSD, etc.

Answer (score 49):

If working with Linux kernel is enough you can simply do

```
ulimit -S -s unlimited
```

That will work because Linux kernel included a patch around 10 years ago that changed argument limit to be based on stack size: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b6a2fea39318e43fee84fa7b0b90d68bed92d2ba

If you don't want unlimited stack space, you can say e.g.

```
ulimit -S -s 100000
```

to limit the stack to 100MB. Note that you need to set stack space to normal stack usage (usually 8 MB) plus the size of the command line you would want to use.

You can query actual limit as follows:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

that will output the maximum command line length in bytes. For example, Ubuntu defaults set this to `2097152` which means roughly 2 MB. If I run with unlimited stack I get `4611686018427387903` which is exactly 2^62 or about 46000 TB. If your command line exceeds *that*, I expect you to be able to workaround the issue by yourself.

Note that if you use `sudo` as in `sudo mv *.dat somewhere/.` running `ulimit` cannot fix that issue because `sudo` resets the stack size before executing the `mv` for real. To workaround that, you have to start root shell with `sudo -s`, then run `ulimit -S -s unlimited` and finally run the command without `sudo` in that root shell.

Comment: That's a hack. How would you know what to set the stack limit to? This also affects other processes started in the same session.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hack. Most of the time this kind of hacks are one-off (how often you manually move huge amount of files anyway?). If you are sure that the process is not going to eat all your RAM, you can set `ulimit -s unlimited` and it will work for practically unlimited files.

Comment: With `ulimit -s unlimited` the actual command line limit is 2^31 or 2 GB. (`MAX_ARG_STRLEN` in kernel source.)

Comment: I have to add that I don't understand why Linux even limits the command line length by default. There's zero technical reason to do because the user process can still waste all the same memory at will so this is not suitable for resource usage limitations either.

Comment: Also note that if you set stack size for your own shell and execute `sudo ...` the stack limit is not inherited because `sudo` always defines its own stack size (which seems to be 8 MB in my system).

Comment: @Kusalananda not necessarily. You can set `ulimit` just for a subshell: `(ulimit -S -s unlimited; mv ...)`. `MAX_ARG_STRLEN`  refers to the maximum length of a *single* command line argument, and it's much smaller than 2^31 (it's actually 32 pages => 128kb - 2Mb)

Comment: @UncleBilly Note that the problem with `sudo` is that even if you have `ulimit -S -s unlimited` in your current shell, executing `sudo mv * foobar` will fail because `sudo` will change your limits before executing the command `mv`. To workaround that you have to do `sudo -s` instead and then set ulimit. If you don't need to use `sudo`, the subshell is a good way to proceed.

Comment: This solution is super simple (no missing with super long lines, which might cause data loss if you get anything wrong), has no side effects (closing shell discards the changes). So much undervoted.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get the same error after unlimiting.

Comment: @geoidesic Do you have old Linux kernel or did you use sudo?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen MacOS Ventura. Don't recall.

Comment: The fact that *Linux specific* solution doesn't work with MacOS is actually expected, right?

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes it's easiest to just write a little script, e.g. in Python:

```
import glob, shutil

for i in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
  shutil.move(i, 'new_dir/' + i)
```

Comment: after accidentally deleting 10% of the files with a botched shell cmd (the `find -exec mv` method), this method was the best because I could easily insert some logic and `print()` statements to make sure it's doing what you want.  For example, print each file it's moving, and stop after 10 files as a sanity check, before committing the whole dir.

Comment: I prefer using [pathlib's iterdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) to specify an input directory, and then `iterdir` returns `Path` objects so you can conveniently access `file.name` or `file.stem`.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
find currentdir -name '*.*' -exec mv {} targetdir \;
```

- `find`: search a folder
- `-name`: match a desired criteria
- `-exec`: run the command that follows
- `{}`: insert the filename found
- `\;`: mark the end of the exec command

Comment: Adding `-maxdepth 1` before `-exec` helped with moving files to a subdirectory, to avoid matching them again once they'd been moved.

Comment: This answer format is very considerate: the example is followed with one-liner explanations of the `find` command arguments.   This format accelerates the learning process

Comment: Turns out if the `targetdir` doesn't exist (was in wrong `cd`), it'll rename the file `targetdir`, then move to the next file and rename *that* file `targetdir` - apparently overwriting the previous file.  In this way it sequentially overwrote and deleted each file...

Comment: `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: Here it is with Alf's suggestion:

`find currentdir -name '*.*' -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} targetdir \;`

Answer (score 11):

The operating system's argument passing limit does not apply to expansions which happen within the shell interpreter. So in addition to using `xargs` or `find`, we can simply use a shell loop to break up the processing into individual `mv` commands:

```sh
for x in *; do case "$x" in *.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) ;; *) mv -- "$x" target ;; esac ; done
```

This uses only POSIX Shell Command Language features and utilities.  This one-liner is clearer with indentation, with unnecessary semicolons removed:

```sh
for x in *; do
  case "$x" in
    *.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) 
       ;; # nothing
    *) # catch-all case
       mv -- "$x" target
       ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: With more than a million files, this will in turn spawn more than a million `mv` processes, instead of just the few needed using the POSIX `find` solution @Gilles posted. In other words, this way results in lots of unnecessary CPU churn.

Comment: @CivFan Another problem is convincing yourself that the modified version is equivalent to the original. It's easy to see that the `case` statement on the result of `*` expansion to filter out several extensions is equivalent to the original `!(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp)` expression.  The `find` answer is in fact not equivalent; it descends into subdirectories (I don't see a `-maxdepth` predicate).

Comment: `-name . -o -type d -prune -o` protects from descending into sub-directories. `-maxdepth` is apparently not POSIX compliant, though that's not mentioned in my `find` man page.

Comment: Rolled back to revision 1. The question doesn't say anything about source or destination variables, so this adds unnecessary cruft to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

A more simple solution using `"$origin"/!(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp)` instead of a catch block:

```sh
for file in "$origin"/!(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp); do mv -- "$file" "$destination" ; done
```

Thanks to @Score_Under

For a multi-line script you can do the following (notice the `;` before the `done` is dropped):

```sh
for file in "$origin"/!(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp); do        # don't copy types *.jpg|*.png|*.bmp
    mv -- "$file" "$destination" 
done
```

To do a more generalized solution that moves all files, you can do the one-liner:

```sh
for file in "$origin"/*; do mv -- "$file" "$destination" ; done
```

Which looks like this if you do indentation:

```sh
for file in "$origin"/*; do
    mv -- "$file" "$destination"
done
```

This takes every file in the origin and moves them one by one to the destination. The quotes around `$file` are necessary in case there are spaces or other special characters in the filenames.

Here is an example of this method that worked perfectly

```sh
for file in "/Users/william/Pictures/export_folder_111210/"*.jpg; do
    mv -- "$file" "/Users/william/Desktop/southland/landingphotos/";
done
```

Comment: You could use something like the original glob in the for-loop to get a closer solution to what's being asked for.

Comment: What do you mean original glob?

Comment: Sorry if that was a little cryptic, I was referring to the glob in the question: `!(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp)`. You could add that to your for-loop by globbing `"$origin"/!(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp)` which would avoid the need for the switch used in Kaz's answer and keep the simple body of the for-loop.

Comment: Awesome Score. I incorporated your comment and updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

For a more aggressive solution than those previously offered, pull up your kernel source and edit `include/linux/binfmts.h`

Increase the size of `MAX_ARG_PAGES` to something larger than 32.  This increases the amount of memory the kernel will allow for program arguments, thereby allowing you to specify your `mv` or `rm` command for a million files or whatever you're doing.  Recompile, install, reboot.

BEWARE!  If you set this too large for your system memory, and then run a command with a lot of arguments BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN!  Be extremely cautious doing this to multi-user systems, it makes it easier for malicious users to use up all your memory!

If you don't know how to recompile and reinstall your kernel manually, it's probably best that you just pretend this answer doesn't exist for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around that restriction while still using `mv` if you don't mind running it a couple times.

You can move portions at a time. Let's say for example you had a long list of alphanumeric file names.

```
mv ./subdir/a* ./
```

That works. Then knock out another big chunk. After a couple moves, you can just go back to using `mv ./subdir/* ./`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents, append this into `.bash_profile`

```
mv() {
  if [[ -d $1 ]]; then #directory mv
    /bin/mv $1 $2
  elif [[ -f $1 ]]; then #file mv
    /bin/mv $1 $2
  else
    for f in $1
    do
      source_path=$f
      #echo $source_path
      source_file=${source_path##*/}
      #echo $source_file
      destination_path=${2%/} #get rid of trailing forward slash

      echo "Moving $f to $destination_path/$source_file"

      /bin/mv $f $destination_path/$source_file
    done
  fi
}
export -f mv
```

Usage

```
mv '*.jpg' ./destination/
mv '/path/*' ./destination/
```