# What does this zsh solution to "the argument list is too long" do?

Tags: files, zsh

I read in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long) from @Gilles the following:

> In zsh, you can load the `mv` builtin:
>
> ```
> setopt extended_glob
> zmodload -Fm zsh/files b:zf_\*
> mv -- ^*.(jpg|png|bmp) targetdir/
> ```

as a solution to the `"mv: Argument list too long”` problem. The answer suggests using zsh's [`mv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-mv) (as opposed to GNU's) but what exactly does this line do?:

```
zmodload -Fm zsh/files b:zf_\*
```

Comment: That was a bug: I showed how to load `zf_mv` and then used `mv`. Fixed.

Comment: reboot works for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way, to look at zsh documentation is using `info`.

If you run `info zsh`, you can use the *index* (think of a *book*'s index) to locate the section that describes the `zmodload` command.

Press <kbd>i</kbd>, then you can enter `zmo` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. You'll get straight to the `zmodload` builtin description which will tell you all about it.

In short, `zmodload -F` loads the module (if not loaded) and enables only the specified *features* from that module.

With `-m`, we enabled the features that <kbd>m</kbd>atch a pattern, here `b:zf_*`. `b:` is for builtin, so the above command loads the `zsh/files` module (see `info -f zsh -n 'The zsh/files Module,'` for details on that) and only enables the builtins whose name starts with `zf_`.

```
zmodload -F zsh/files
```

loads the module, but doesn't enable any feature:

```
$ zmodload -FlL zsh/files
zmodload -F zsh/files -b:chgrp -b:chown -b:ln -b:mkdir -b:mv -b:rm -b:rmdir -b:sync -b:zf_chgrp -b:zf_chown -b:zf_ln -b:zf_mkdir -b:zf_mv -b:zf_rm -b:zf_rmdir -b:zf_sync
```

lists the features of that module specifying which are currently enabled (none for now). You'll notice there's both a `mv` and `zf_mv` builtin.

```
$ zmodload -mF zsh/files 'b:zf_*'
$ zmodload -FlL zsh/files
zmodload -F zsh/files -b:chgrp -b:chown -b:ln -b:mkdir -b:mv -b:rm -b:rmdir -b:sync +b:zf_chgrp +b:zf_chown +b:zf_ln +b:zf_mkdir +b:zf_mv +b:zf_rm +b:zf_rmdir +b:zf_sync
```

You'll notice the `zf_mv` builtin has been enabled, but not the `mv` one (same for the other builtins). That means, those builtin versions of the system commands have been enabled, but without overriding the system one:

```
$ type zf_mv
zf_mv is a shell builtin
$ type mv
mv is /bin/mv
```

Now that you have a builtin `mv`, **as `zf_mv`**, not `mv`, you can do:

```
zf_mv -- ^*.(jpg|png|bmp) targetdir/
```

Because `zf_mv` is builtin, there's no `execve()` system call, so you won't hit the `Too many args` limit associated with it.

Of course, you can also do:

```
zmodload zsh/files # without -F, all the features are enabled
mv -- ^*.(jpg|png|bmp) targetdir/
```

But beware that replaces the system's `mv` with `zsh` builtin equivalent.

To overcome the `E2BIG` `execve()` error (the *Too many args* upon executing an external command), `zsh` also provides with a `zargs` function.

You run:

```
autoload zargs # in ~/.zshrc if you use it often
```

To mark it for autoloading.

Then you can use:

```
zargs -- ^*.(jpg|png|bmp) -- mv -t targetdir/
```

(here assuming GNU `mv` for the `-t` option). `zargs` will run as many `mv` commands as necessary to avoid the E2BIG (as `xargs` would do).

Answer (score -3):

There is an universal solution that not rely on bashism: `xargs`.

`xargs` reads a stream of arguments from `stdin` and then pass them to the arbitrary specified utility. In your case that is how command line should look like:

```
# find -E /source/dir -iregex ".*\.(jpg|png|bmp)" | xargz -n 1 -J % mv % /target/dir
```

Here `-E` means that `find` used the modern regexes (for|alternatives), `-n 1` means that incoming stream will be splitted into single arguments, `-J %` means that each argument will be substituted at the next occurence of the `%` char.

`-J %` is necessary because `xargs` appends an argument to the end of child command by default. Absence of `-J %` is equivalent to the `xargs -n 1 -J % mv /target/dir %` that is definitely not what you want.

Comment: That is not universal, that's FreeBSD/NetBSD/OS/X specific (for -E, -iregex, -J that are not standard). (ITYM xargs, not xargz btw)

Comment: There is no bashism here. It's a zsh feature. And the question isn't about doing this (that's what the linked question was about, and I give several solutions, including portable ones, unlike yours which only works on BSD because of `-J` and chokes on several characters in file names), but how this particular zsh solution works.

Comment: That will also break on file names that contain spacing or quoting characters.

Comment: that also recurses in the sub-directories which was not asked for.