# Efficient data extraction from multiple files to a single CSV file

Tags: text-processing, zsh, csv, xml

I have a large collection of XML files with the same exact structure:

```
$ cat file_<ID>.xml
... 
 ... 
   ...
      <double>1.2342</double>
      <double>2.3456</double>
      ...
   ...
 ... 
...
```

where the number of such `<double>` entries in each XML file is fixed and known (in my particular case, 168).

I need to build a single `csv` file with the content  of all these XML files stored as follows:

```
file_0001 1.2342 2.3456 ... 
file_0002 1.2342 2.3456 ...
```

etc.

How can I do this efficiently?

---

The best I have come up with is this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

for x in $path_to_xmls/*.xml; do 

    # 1) Get the doubles ignoring everything else
    # 2) Remove line breaks within the same file
    # 3) Add a new line at the end to construct the CSV file
    # 4) Join the columns together

    cat $x | grep -F '<double>' | \ 
    sed -r 's/.*>([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*).*?/\1/' | \
    tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e '$a\'  |  >> table_numbers.csv

    echo ${x:t} >> file_IDs.csv
done
    
paste file_IDs table_numbers.csv > final_table.csv
```

When I time the above script in a folder with ~10K XML files I get:

```
./from_xml_to_csv.sh  100.45s user 94.84s system 239% cpu 1:21.48 total
```

not terrible, but I am hoping to work with 100x or 1000x  more files.  How can I make this processing more efficient?

Also, with my solution above, could I ever end up in a situation where the glob expansion reaches a limit, e.g. when working with millions of files?  (the typical [`"too many args"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156119/4531) problem).

### Update

For anyone interested in a great solution to this problem, please read @mikeserve's answer. It is the fastest and the one that scales up the best by far.

Comment: I'm no shell expert but for the `too many args` there's always `xargs`. Or you could export function then use `find...-exec func{} +...` for huge dirs. I do recall a limit of 32768 dirs on some bsd distro that screwed with some command combo. You could skip `sed` and use `tr` only to remove tag if element contents are just `[0-9.]` as element is just `<double></double>`, `tr` can do all that. Do you need to `cat` or can redirect straight to `grep`. Maybe can cut down on pipes and use more redirection.

Comment: It's hard to answer XML processing questions when your XML isn't valid. Any chance you could do a more complete version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding glob expansion possibly exceeding a limit - yes and no. The shell's already running, and so it won't stop. But if you were to pass the entire globbed array as arguments to a single command, then yes, that is a definite possibility. The portable and robust way to handle this involves `find`...

```
find . \! -name . -prune -name pattern -type f -exec cat {} + | ...
```

...which will only `cat` regular files in the current directory with a name which matches *`pattern`*, but will also only invoke `cat` as many times as is necessary to avoid exceeding `ARG_MAX`.

In fact, though, since you have a GNU `sed` we can *almost* do the whole thing with just `sed` in a `find` script.

```sh
cd /path/to/xmls
find . \! -name . -prune -name \*.xml -type f -exec  \
    sed -sne'1F;$x;/\n*\( \)*<\/*double>/!d' \
        -e  '$s//\1/gp;H' {} + | paste -d\\0 - -
```

I thought of another way. This will be **very** fast, but it absolutely depends on there being exactly 168 matches per file, and there can only be the one `.` dot in the filenames.

```sh
(   export LC_ALL=C; set '' - -
    while [ "$#" -lt 168 ]; do set "$@$@"; done
    shift "$((${#}-168))"
    find . \! -name . -prune -name \*.xml -type f      \
              -exec  grep -F '<double>' /dev/null {} + |
    tr \<: '>>' | cut -d\> -f1,4 | paste -d\  "$@"     |
    sed 'h;s|./[^>]*>||g;x;s|\.x.*||;s|..||;G;s|\n| |'
)
```

As requested, here's a little breakdown of how this command works:

1. `( ... )`

   - In the first place, the whole little script is run within its own subshell because there are a few global environmental properties that we'll be altering in the course of its execution, and this way when the job is done all of the properties we alter will be restored to their original values - whatever they were.
2. `export LC_ALL=C; set '' - -`

   - By setting the current locale to `C` we can save our filters a lot of effort. In a UTF-8 locale any char might be represented by one or several bytes a piece, and any char found will need to be selected out of a group of many thousand possibles. In the C locale each char is a single byte, and there are only 128 of them. It makes char matching a much quicker affair overall.
   - The `set` statement changes the shell's positional parameters. Doing `set '' - -` sets `$1` to `\0`, and `$2` and `$3` to `-`.
3. `while ... set "$@$@"; done; shift ...`

   - Basically the whole point of this statement is to get an array of 168 dashes. We'll be using `paste` later to replace sequential sets of 167 newlines with spaces, while preserving the 168th. The most simple way to do this is to give it 168 argument references to `-` stdin and tell it to paste all of those together.
4. `find ... -exec grep -F '<double>' /dev/null' ...`

   - The `find` bit has been previously discussed, but with `grep` we print only those lines which can be matched against the `-F`ixed string `<double>`. By making `grep`'s first argument `/dev/null` - which is a file that can *never* match our string - we ensure that `grep` is always searching 2 or more file arguments for every invocation. When invoked with 2 or more named search files `grep` will always print the filename like `file_000.xml:` at the head of every output line.
5. `tr \<: '>>'`

   - Here we translate every occurrence in `grep`'s output of either `:` or `<` characters to `>`.
   - At this point a sample matched line will look like `./file_000.xml>    >double>0.0000>/double>`.
6. `cut -d\> -f1,4`

   - `cut` will strip from its output all of its input which cannot be found within either the 1st or 4th fields as divided by `>` chars.
   - At this point a sample matched line will look like `./file_000.xml>0.0000`.
7. `paste -d\  "$@"`

   - Already discussed, but here we `paste` input lines in batches of 168.
   - At this point 168 matched lines occur together like: `./file_000.xml>0.000 .../file_000.xml>0.167`
8. `sed 'h;s|./[^>]*>||g;x;s|\.xml.*||;s|..||;G;s|\n| |'`

   - Now the faster, smaller utilities have already done the majority of the work. On a multicore system, they've probably even done it concurrently. And those utilities - *especially* `cut` and `paste` are far faster at what they do than any attempt at emulation we might do with higher-level utilities like `sed`, or, even worse, `awk`. But I've taken it as far as I could imagine I might do this far, and I have to call on `sed`.
   - First I `h`old a copy of every input line, then I `g`lobally remove every occurrence of the pattern `./[^>]*>` in pattern space - so every occurrence of the filename. At this point `sed`'s pattern space looks like: `0.000 0.0001...0.167`
   - Then I e`x`change `h`old and pattern spaces and remove everything from `\.xml.*` on - so everything from the first filename on the saved copy of the line on. I then strip the first two chars - or `./` as well - and at this point pattern space looks like `file_000`.
   - So all that remains is to stick them together. I `G`et a copy of `h`old space appended to pattern space following a `\n`ewline char, then I `s///`ubstitute the `\n`ewline for a space.
   - And so, finally, pattern space looks like `file_000 0.000...0.167`. And that is what `sed` writes to output for each file `find` passes to `grep`.

Comment: Thanks -- but I am afraid I get: `sed: -e expression #2, char 17: unknown option to 's'
find: 'grep' terminated by signal 13
find: 'grep' terminated by signal 13`. I am using **GNU's** variants of these tools in OS X.

Comment: More specifically: `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`, `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` and `grep (GNU grep) 2.21`.

Comment: Thanks -- For some reason this is very slow (slower than the solution in the OP) on my machine. I'm really surprised to see this, since your solution looks definitely cleaner and involves less piping etc. from what I can see. Hmm, I'm still investigating.

Comment: Thanks -- This is interesting -- It doesn't seem to work yet, I basically end up with `csv` with two XML filenames per line, i.e. first line looks like `file1.xml file2.xml` , second line like `file3.xml file4.xml`, etc.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina - the bottom one works. And it's *fast*. Still, though, the two names per line was because I had a `-n` there, and it shouldn't have been. So just `sed -se` not `sed -sne`.

Comment: Thanks -- This is really strange. I have updated my OP with your latest solution.

Comment: And by the way, your assumption is correct (one dot per file and 168 numbers per file)

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina - oh - `zsh`? `zsh` does a weird thing with `$#` in math expansions. Sorry I should have done `${#}` to protect against that in the first place.

Comment: That worked! @mikeserve. I only had to fix `type -f` to have it be `type f` (editing your query if you don't mind). Impressive speed! I hope this is useful for others -- extracting structured data from many files into a csv file. I renamed the OP to signal that.

Comment: Awesome. By the way, I saw your posterior edits to the answer, which is great. Would you mind elaborating perhaps a bit on how the second solution works? It may help others adapt this answer to future multiple-file to-single-CSV transformation questions :).

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! I tried the first solution (with GNU versions) but I ended up with the same `file1.xml file2.xml\nfile3.xml file4.xml ...` pattern as before.

Comment: Thanks @mikeserv! Both solutions now work great. This a huge speed up from the original solution in the OP (and 100X faster than a Python solution that properly loads xml's one by one to build a CSV dataframe in Pandas). Current times in my machine: Sol (1): 19 seconds. Sol (2): 14 seconds, both transforming ~10K XML files into a single CSV file.

Comment: Thanks @mikeserv I prepended Sol (1) with `export LC_ALL=C;` and the timing for it was still ~ 20.28 seconds (i.e. ~unchanged).

Comment: The second solution still runs in ~ 15s

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina - even with all of the additional setup and the additional execs and etc, it's this kind of stuff that makes shell pipelines powerful. Unix is timeshared - and so if there are multiple processes running in a foreground process group they will get execution priority - and each winds up operating on its own processor core. And so there is no delay when the data is passed around - it's just many hands making light work. The key is to make the execs *count* - a *single* pipeline which handles all data in a job from start to finish, and they're almost always worth it.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```bsh
awk -F '[<>]' '
      NR!=1 && FNR==1{printf "\n"} 
      FNR==1{sub(".*/", "", FILENAME); sub(".xml$", "", FILENAME); printf FILENAME} 
      /double/{printf " %s", $3}
      END{printf "\n"}
    ' $path_to_xml/*.xml > final_table.csv
```

#### Explanation:

- `awk`: use the program `awk`, I tested it with GNU awk 4.0.1
- `-F '[<>]'`: use `<` and `>` as field separators
- `NR!=1 && FNR==1{printf "\n"}`: if it is not the first line overall (`NR!=1`) but the first line of a file (`FNR==1`) print a newline
- `FNR==1{sub(".*/", "", FILENAME); sub(".xml$", "", FILENAME); printf FILENAME}`: if it is the first line of a file, strip away anything up to the last `/` (`sub(".*/", "", FILENAME)`) in the name of the file (`FILENAME`), strip a trailing `.xml` (`sub(".xml$", "", FILENAME)`) and print the result (`printf FILENAME`)
- `/double/{printf " %s", $3}` if a line contains "double" (`/double/`), print a space followed by the third field (`printf " %s", $3`). Using `<` and `>` as separators this would be the the number (with the first field being anything before the first `<` and the second field being `double`). If you want, you can format the numbers here. For example by using `%8.3f` instead of `%s` any number will be printed with 3 decimal places and an overall length (including dot and decimal places) of at least 8.
- END{printf "\n"}: after the last line print an additional newline (this could be optional)
- `$path_to_xml/*.xml`: the list of files
- `> final_table.csv`: put the result into `final_table.csv` by redirecting the output

---

In the case of "argument list to long" errors, you can use `find` with parameter `-exec` to generate a file list instead of passing it directly:

```bsh
find $path_to_xml -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.xml' -exec awk -F '[<>]' '
      NR!=1 && FNR==1{printf "\n"} 
      FNR==1{sub(".*/", "", FILENAME); sub(".xml$", "", FILENAME); printf FILENAME} 
      /double/{printf " %s", $3}
      END{printf "\n"}
    ' {} + > final_table.csv
```

#### Explanation:

- `find $path_to_xml`: tell `find` to list files in `$path_to_xml`
- `-maxdepth 1`: do not descend into subfolders of `$path_to_xml`
- `-type f`: only list regular files (this also excludes `$path_to_xml` itself)
- `-name '*.xml': only list files that match the pattern`*.xml`, this needs to be quoted else the shell will try to expand the pattern
- `-exec COMMAND {} +`: run the command `COMMAND` with the matching files as parameters in place of `{}`. `+` indicates that multiple files may be passed at once, which reduces forking. If you use `\;` (`;` needs to be quoted else it is interpreted by the shell) instead of `+` the command is run for each file separately.

You can also use `xargs` in conjunction with `find`:

```bsh
find $path_to_xml -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.xml' -print0 |
 xargs -0 awk -F '[<>]' '
      NR!=1 && FNR==1{printf "\n"} 
      FNR==1{sub(".*/", "", FILENAME); sub(".xml$", "", FILENAME); printf FILENAME} 
      /double/{printf " %s", $3}
      END{printf "\n"}
    ' > final_table.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `-print0`: output list of files separated by null characters
- `|` (pipe): redirects standard output of `find` to the standard input of `xargs`
- `xargs`: builds and runs commands from standard input, i.e. run a command for each argument (here file names) passed.
- `-0`: direct `xargs` to assume arguments are separated by null characters

---

```bsh
awk -F '[<>]' '      
      BEGINFILE {sub(".*/", "", FILENAME); sub(".xml$", "", FILENAME); printf FILENAME} 
      /double/{printf " %s", $3}
      ENDFILE {printf "\n"}
    ' $path_to_xml/*.xml > final_table.csv
```

where `BEGINFILE`, `ENDFILE` are called when changing file (if your awk supports it).

Comment: Thanks -- I'm afraid I now get `"argument list too long: awk"` .

Comment: This is great. Thanks!! -- The explanations are very helpful. I measured the latest solutions and they don't have the "argument list too long" errors anymore. They run on ~20 secs against 10K XML files, making them on par with @mikeserv's slowest solution, but slower than mikeserv's faster solution. This is definitely a GREAT and very clear solution to the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Please, on behalf of future maintenance programmers and sysadmins - DON'T use a regex to parse XML. XML is a structured data type, and it is NOT well suited for regex parsing - you can 'fake it' by pretending it's plain text, but there's a bunch of semantically identical things in XML that don't parse the same. You can embed linefeeds, and have unary tags for example.

Thus - use a parser - I have mocked up some source data, because your XML isn't valid. Give me a more complete sample, and I'll give you a more complete answer.

At a basic level - we extract the `double` nodes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new;
$twig -> parse ( \*DATA ); 

foreach my $double ( $twig -> get_xpath('//double') ) {
   print $double -> trimmed_text,"\n";
}

__DATA__
<root> 
 <subnode> 
   <another_node>
      <double>1.2342</double>
      <double>2.3456</double>
      <some_other_tag>fish</some_other_tag>
   </another_node>
 </subnode>
</root>
```

This prints:

```
1.2342
2.3456
```

So we expand this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Text::CSV;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
my $csv  = Text::CSV->new;

#open our results file
open( my $output, ">", "results.csv" ) or die $!;
#iterate each XML File. 
foreach my $filename ( glob("/path/to/xml/*.xml") ) {
    #parse it
    $twig->parsefile($filename);
    #extract all the text of all the 'double' elements. 
    my @doubles = map { $_->trimmed_text } $twig->get_xpath('//double');
    #print it as comma separated. 
    $csv->print( $output, [ $filename, @doubles ] );

}
close($output);
```

I think that should do the trick (without sample data, I can't say for sure). But note - by using an XML parser we don't get tripped up with some of the XML reformatting that can be done perfectly validly (as according to the XML spec). By using a CSV parser, we aren't going to get caught out by any fields with embedded commas or line feeds.

If you're looking for more specific nodes - you can specify a more detailed path. As it is, the above just looks for any instance of `double`. But you can use:

```
get_xpath("/root/subnode/another_node/double")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this single liner for each file. 
The awk multiple delimiters does efficient splitting and tr concats all lines in memory , rather than on disk.

```
for f in `ls *.xml` ; 
do 
     echo $f,`grep double $f | awk  -F  '[<>]' '{print $3}' | tr '\n' ','`; 
done
```

I can not profile this at my end - since I do not have the same data, but my hunch is that it should be faster.

Apart from that, this is the easiest problem to divide and rule - if you have access to multiple machines or farms, you can just divided up the whole task to multiple machines and finally concat all the outputs into one file. This way command line limits and memory can also be managed.

Comment: can you explain the down-vote instead of the eat,shoot and leave ?

Comment: In most (all?) cases `grep` is not needed in conjunction with `awk`. Instead of `grep double $f | awk -F '[<>]' '{print $3}' you can just use `awk -F '[<>]' '/double/ {print $3}' $f`. Also `tr` is not really needed here: `echo $f$(awk -F '[<>]' '/double/{printf ",%d", $3} END{print ""}' $f`

Comment: To be clear, neither was the downvote from me nor did I try to explain why you got a downvote (personally I do not think it is warranted). It was just something I noticed when reading your answer.

Comment: @Adaphon - the downvote is mine, and it is primarily for `for f in $(ls *.xml); do echo $f, $(grep double $f | awk ...); done`... That code leaves so much open to interpretation, it might as well not be a program. It completely depends on IFS and shell-glob settings, and doesn't bother to check or set either. While the likelihood is small, it is possible that, given the right conditions, that code could erase and/or overwrite on-disk files and data.

Comment: @Adaephon - you are right ,a single awk could do it ..

Comment: @mikeserv - so is using `find` a better idea than `ls` ? I am okay with the downvote - no issues there as long as there  is something to learn with it !

Comment: It depends. If you need to take an action on each of the results then probably, and that's because `find` can `-exec`. But each situation is different. But that's not really what I was talking about though. If you're going to split with `IFS` you *have* to set it first. Don't rely on default values - especially not in a public forum where anyone can copy and paste what you've written directly to their terminal prompt regardless of what else they had previously pasted there. And you also have to take care *not* to glob. If the split results contain shell globs that match, it gets bad.

Comment: And @Adaephon, by the way, whether or not `awk` can find the match on its own, if speed is what is asked for, then you *should* use `grep`. `grep` is *far* faster at finding a match than `awk`.

Comment: @mikeserv That may depend on the implementation and the specific case. I did a quick check on some log files (cumulative size around 1.5 GiB, on ramdisk), searching for lines containing "line" (over all around 7.5 million matches) and for me `grep` was (*far*) slower. `grep 'line' logfiles/* > /dev/null` (GNU grep 2.16) takes about 15 seconds to finish, while `gawk '/line/{print}' > /dev/null` (GNU awk 4.0.1) takes about 8.5 seconds and `mawk '/line/{print} > /dev/null' (Mike's AWK 1.3.3) only needs about 2.9 seconds.

Comment: @Adaephon - that doesn't make any sense. Except that you're doing `logfiles/*` for `grep` and not so for `gawk`.  You should be using `-F` though if you're not searching for a regexp.

Comment: @mikeserv Sorry, typing error, of course all three commands used `logfiles/*` as filelist. `grep -F 'line' logfiles/* > /dev/null` takes even longer with around 30 seconds. While `grep -P 'line' logfiles/* > /dev/null` (using PCRE) beats at least `gawk` with a time of 6 seconds.  On a completely different machine with newer versions (grep 2.21, gawk 4.1.3, mawk 1.3.4) it looks different: `gawk` 8.0 s, `mawk` 4.2 s, `grep` 2.8 s, `grep -F` 3.4 s and `grep -P` 5.2 s. Here `grep` is indeed faster than `awk`. So, it really depends. (and `grep -F` does not help performance)

Comment: @Adaephon - wow. It's ... weird. In my experience `awk` is always the slowest tool in the box - only a step ahead of the turtles like `perl` or `python`, `sed` is faster, `grep` still more so, and `dd`, `expand`, `cut`, `paste` set the pace. This has been true with *many* different sets of tools that I have used - not just GNU. I'm thoroughly confused/intrigued by your results.  Are the commands interpreting charsets in different ways?

Answer (score -1):

You’re writing twice for every file. This is probably the most expensive part. You’ll instead want to try to keep the whole thing in memory, probably in an array. Then write once in the end.

Look into `ulimit` if you start hitting memory limits. If you’re increasing this workload to 10-100x, you’re looking at maybe 10-100 GB of memory. You could batch this in a loop that does so-many-thousands per iteration. I’m not sure if this needs to be a repeatable process, but get more sophisticated if you need it to be faster/more robust. Otherwise, hand stitch the batches afterward.

You’re also spawning several processes per file -- every pipe you have. You could do the whole parsing/munging (grep/sed/tr) with a single process. After the grep, Zsh can handle the other translations via expansions (see `man zshexpn`). Or, you could do all the single `sed` line in one invocation with multiple expressions. `sed` may be faster if you avoid the `-r` (extended regex) and non-greediness. Your `grep` could just pull out matching lines from many files at once, and write to intermediate temp files. Know your bottlenecks, though, and don’t fix what’s not.