# Append all files in a directory as cli arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments

I need to run a command that looks like this

`mycli --file test.zip --file another_test.zip`

How could I run that dynamically with all zip files in a directory? I'm sure I could pipe the files from a find command, but I don't know how to actually append them as arguments to another command and my bash-fu is not great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an array:

```bsh
unset -v args
declare -a args
for file in *.zip
do
  args+=( --file "$file" )
done
mycli "${args[@]}"
```

Or, POSIXly:

```bsh
set --
for file in *.zip
do
  set -- "$@" --file "$file"
done
mycli "$@"
```

Or, assuming GNU tools:

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.zip' -printf '--file\0%f\0' |
  xargs -0 -- mycli
```

A relevant difference between the array-based approach and the `xargs`-based one: while the former may fail with an ["Argument list too long"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/315749) error (assuming `mycli` is not a builtin command), the latter will not, and will run `mycli` more than once instead. Note, however, that in this last case all but the last invocation's argument lists may end with `--file` (and the following one start with a file name). Depending on your use case you may be able to use a combination of `xargs`' options (e.g. `-n` and `-x`) to prevent this.

Also, note that `find` will include [hidden files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) in its output, while the array-based alternatives will not, unless the `dotglob` shell option is set in Bash or, in a POSIX shell, both the `*.zip` and `.*.zip` globbing expressions are used. For details and caveats on this:
[How do you move all files (including hidden) from one directory to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6393/315749).

Comment: Thanks so much for not only providing an answer, but also providing multiple ways as well as an explanation of the differences! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have many thousands of files (this would generate an "Argument list too long" error), then you may do it like this with the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
mycli ./*.zip(P:--file:)
```

Or, from the `bash` shell:

```bsh
zsh -c 'exec mycli ./*.zip(P:--file:)'
```

(I'm using `exec` here to replace the `zsh` shell with the `mycli` process, for a bit of efficiency.)

The `P` filename globbing qualifier prepends the given string (here, `--file`) as a separate word before each element that the glob expands to.

To include hidden files, add `D` before `P`, and to limit the matching to only regular files, add `.`:

```bsh
zsh -c 'exec mycli ./*.zip(.DP:--file:)'
```

For a recursive globbing down into subdirectories:

```bsh
zsh -c 'exec mycli ./**/*.zip(.DP:--file:)'
```

... and to order the files in order of modification timestamp (would you want to do so), add `om` as you added `D` and `.` before.

Answer (score 2):

this works:

```
ls *.zip | xargs printf "--file %s " | xargs echo mycli
```

Once you're satisfied with the resulting command, remove the `echo` in the second `xargs` and re-run.

If you have zip files whose name have spaces or other shell meta characters, it gets a bit more complicated though.