# -bash: /usr/bin/mv: Argument list too long

Tags: ubuntu

When I am using this command `mv * ..`, I am getting the error `-bash: /usr/bin/mv: Argument list too long`. I do understand the reason this occurs is because bash actually expands the asterisk to every matching file, producing a very long command line. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving "mv: Argument list too long"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is not in bash but in the `execve()` system call used to execute external commands. You could do:

```
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -r0 mv -t .. --
```

Since `printf` is builtin in `bash`, there's no `execve()` at that point. And it's `xargs` job to split the list of arguments so as to avoid that limit. Here using the GNU-specific `-t` option of GNU `mv`.

With `zsh`, you can load the `mv` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/files
mv -- * ..
```

Or use its `zargs` helper to do the splitting:

```
autoload -Uz zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs -r -- ./* -- mv -t ..
```

You can replace `./*` with `./*(D)` to also move hidden files or add the `oN` glob qualifier to skip the  sorting of file names, or the `N` glob qualifier (with `zargs -r`) to avoid the error if there's no matching file.

```
zargs -r -- ./*(ND) -- mv -t ..
```

Same as:

```
print -rNC1 ./*(ND) | xargs -r0 mv -t ..
```

But without the dependency to GNU `xargs`.

On Linux (the kernel typically used on Ubuntu), you can  also raise that `execve()` limit by raising the `stacksize` resource limit:

```
bash-5.1$ /bin/true {1..200000}
bash: /bin/true: Argument list too long
bash-5.1$ ulimit -s unlimited
bash-5.1$ /bin/true {1..200000}
bash-5.1$
```

It's not fully unlimited (at least not in current versions of the kernel):

```
bash-5.1$ /bin/true {1..2000000}
bash: /bin/true: Argument list too long
```

Note that the limit is on the cumulated size of the arguments and the environment variables passed to `execve()`, but the computation is not just the sum of the bytes in there and how it's done varies between OS and version thereof.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it in two or more steps:

```bsh
mv [a-k]* ..    # or some other pattern matching a subset of the files
mv -- * ..
```

Or in a loop,

```bsh
for name in *; do
    mv -- "$name" ..
done
```

(But this would call `mv` for each and every name individually.)

Or get `find` to help you:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -t .. -- {} +
```

This would find all names in the current directory, and using GNU `mv`, would move them to the directory above with as few invocations of `mv` as possible.

Without GNU `mv`, but with a `find` that still know the non-standard `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` predicates,

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$@" ..' sh {} +
```

None of these variations care about name collisions.  You should test on data that is properly backed up.

Comment: See `find . ! -name . -prune -exec ...` for the standard equivalent of `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`. Note that `find` doesn't exclude hidden files.