# -bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long

Tags: ubuntu

When I am using this command `ls repo/* | xargs -I {} cp {} backup_repo/`, I am getting the error `-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long`. I do understand the reason this occurs is because bash actually expands the asterisk to every matching file, producing a very long command line. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [-bash: /usr/bin/mv: Argument list too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675662/bash-usr-bin-mv-argument-list-too-long)

Comment: You already asked this in slightly different way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving "mv: Argument list too long"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128559/solving-mv-argument-list-too-long)

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` to see your current limits.

A better way:

```
find repo -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty  \
    cp --target-directory=./backup_repro/
```

It's a bad idea to have your backup directory in the same directory as the files you're backing up. It could lead to backing up a backup that contains a backup that contains a ... and the size of a backup approaches infinity.

Read `man find xargs cp`.

Comment: Note that `-name '*'` is rather pointless. It's not like shells' `*` glob and doesn't exclude hidden file. The only thing it does with some `find` implementations (including the OP's GNU `find`) is exclude the files whose name cannot fully be decoded as text. If you wanted to exclude hidden files, you'd need `LC_ALL=C` and `! -name '.*'`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a copy of `repo` in `backup_repo`, use `rsync`:

```bsh
rsync -a repo/ backup_repo
```

Or, if all you need is a backup, make a `tar` archive,

```bsh
tar -c -f repo.tar repo
```

If you want to copy only the visible names that `*` expands to inside `repo`, and to skip any hidden names (like `.git`), then you could possibly use

```bsh
printf '%s\0' repo/* | xargs -0 -I {} cp -R -- {} backup_repo
```

or, assuming GNU `cp`,

```bsh
printf '%s\0' repo/* | xargs -0 cp -t backup_repo -R --
```

The `printf` utility is built into the `bash` shell and will therefore not have the same limitation on argument list size as an external utility like `ls` would have.